# allow only distinct values in ComboBox

Tags: c#, winforms

In my project, I'm trying to populate `ComboBox` from `DataSet`. I succeeded in populating but the values inside the `ComboBox` are not distinct (Because it shows the values present in `DataSet`). I cant bind the `ComboBox` to `DataSet` because I'm adding "Select" text at first of populating the values.

```
ComboBox --> cmb
DataSet --> ds
DataSet Column Name --> value(string)
```

---

Here is my code:

```
cmb.Items.Clear();
cmb.Items.Add("Select");
for (int intCount = 0; intCount < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; intCount++)
{
    cmb.Items.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[intCount][value].ToString());
}
cmb.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

How would I allow distinct values (or restrict duplicate values) inside the `ComboBox`?

Comment: How would you pass ids, in this case? You're adding only values to a `ComboBox`. I would directly bind a `ComboBox` to a *datasource*, using its property, `DataTextField` and `DataValueField` and `DataTextFormatString`, if necessary.

Comment: I dont know anything that you mentioned :) anyhow I will learn them now

Comment: Do you need use DisplayMember and ValueMember for ComboBox ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
for (int intCount = 0; intCount < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; intCount++)
{
     var val=ds.Tables[0].Rows[intCount][value].ToString();

     //check if it already exists
     if(!cmb.Items.Contains(val))
     {
            cmb.Items.Add(val);
     }
}
```

Comment: All answers were good but this easy way of doing looks better to me. thank you.

Comment: @RavinderGangadher Should "Hi", "Thanks" and taglines and salutations be removed from posts?
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-and-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts  _IMHO, delete the "thank"-"now all is ok" comment, better is vote or mark answer._

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

```
cmb.Items.Clear();
cmb.Items.Add("Select");
cmb.Items.AddRange(dds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                           .Select(x=>x[value].ToString())
                           .Distinct());
```

- It uses linq to select the values, applying [Distinct()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct.aspx) selects unique values
- You can apply an [OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderby.aspx) if you want the values to be sorted.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i = 0; i < cmb.Items.Count; i++)
{
    for(int y = 0; y < cmb.Items.Count; y++)
    {
         if( y != i && cmb.Items[i].Text == cmb.Items[y].Text)
         {
              cmb.Items.RemoveAt(i);
              break;
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is helpful when you want to check against text of drop down. Thanks..!!

Answer (score 0):

you can still bind a dataset. after you bind it add the select item to the combobox at the index position you want

Answer (score 0):

**Get Distict values in Datatable & then fill the combo:**

```
DataView dvw = new DataView(ds.Tables[0]);
DataTable table = dvw.ToTable(true, value);

cmb.Items.Clear();
cmb.Items.Add("Select");
for (int intCount = 0; intCount < table.Rows.Count; intCount++)
{
    cmb.Items.Add(table.Rows[intCount][value].ToString());
}
cmb.SelectedIndex = 0;
```