# retrieving data into combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I cannot really understand what is happening. From my previous thread, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17405517/combox-wpf-data-not-showing-when-i-use-navigation-buttons), I asked why data was not retrieving in the combobox but having no problems with textboxes. All I want is to retrieve each record by using navigation buttons. Is there anything I have missed out for combobox properties section? Is there altenative solution out there to what I have done? All coding is available from my previous thread, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17405517/combox-wpf-data-not-showing-when-i-use-navigation-buttons), is there a problem with visual studio component?

**Many thanks**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My friend, you are so far from how this is supposed to be done. You're talking about a `ComboBox`, but I think that you must mean a `ListView`. The only `ComboBox` in your code has `ComboBoxItem`s hard coded inside, so I guess you're not talking about that one.

Either way, this is how you fix your problem:

Add a class similar to this for your data:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string HealthDetails { get; set; }
}
```

Add this dependency property to your code behind:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty PeopleProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("People", typeof(ObservableCollection<Person>), typeof(MainWindow), new UIPropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<Person>()));

public ObservableCollection<Person> People
{
    get { return (ObservableCollection<Person>)GetValue(PeopleProperty); }
    set { SetValue(PeopleProperty, value); }
}
```

Fill the `People` collection with your data. Then most importantly, bind to this collection. Previously, you were binding to the whole `MainWindow.cs` class... change this

```
<ListView Height="134" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="listView1"  
    ItemsSource="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="384">
```

to this:

```
<ListView Height="134" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="listView1" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding People}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="384">
```

It works just fine for me. However, your navigation buttons will never work like this. There are so many things wrong here, I simply don't have time to fix it all for you. Here is a summary of where you are going wrong:

1. Data should never be fetched in the code behind of a `Window`.
2. Data should be stored in a property that supports the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.
3. Data should not be reloaded when iterating through the collection in the UI (unless you're expecting continuous updates).
4. Data objects such as `DataTable`s should not be displayed in UI.
5. You should bind the `ItemsSource` property of collection controls to collection properties in your view model or code behind.
6. You should bind the `SelectedItem` property of collection controls to a property of the correct type in your view model or code behind.
7. In your button click handlers, set this selected item in your view model or code behind and the UI controls will automatically update.

Comment: Sheridan - Thanks for your valuable time in helping me out.